# I am using sed with a regex in Linux but not getting the expected answer

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file in which the content looks like this

```
1234 Name Surname Address
```

and I should have an output file like this

```
(123) Name Surname Address
```

I am using the Linux `sed` command

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\./&/g' file_name
```

But my command doesn't change the input file at all.

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\).\(.*\)/(\1)\2/g' yourfile
```

**Explanation:**

- `^\([0-9]\{3\}\)` - first 3 digits ( group 1 )
- `.`              - matching any one character
- `\(.*\)`         - remaining content ( group 2 )
- `(\1)`            - accessing the first group using `\1` and
  added parenthesis around it.
- `\2`             - accessing the second group

Comment: Thank you, please explain the sed entry u have wrote.

Comment: Your sed comand is very good but what I shoul do not to overide the 3rd caracter. For example if I have 0268211456 in an input file the result will be (026)211456. Sincerely,

Comment: @MxM give a try to this command `sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]+)/(\1)\2/g' file`

Comment: @MxM, I didn't get `what I should do not to overide the 3rd character`

Comment: @MxM, What is your expected result for this line `0268211456 some text`

Comment: (0268)211456 some text

Comment: @MxM, Then try this : `echo "0268211456 some text" | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/(\1)\2/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a two capture groups just one is enough and also don't need to capture the remaining characters after the numbers,

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]/(\1)/g' file
(123) Name Surname Adress
```

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})[0-9]/(\1)/g' file
(123) Name Surname Adress
```

**Explanation:**

```
([0-9]{3})  # Captures first three numbers.
[0-9]       # Matches the last number.
(\1)        # In the replacement part, it replaces the four numbers by `(captured group)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `awk`

```
awk '{$1="("substr($1,1,3)")"}1' file
(123) Name Surname Address
```

It adds parentheses to the three first characters of field `#1` and prints it.
And its shorter than  `sed` :)